# Problemas con el tiempo de ejecucion al momento de exportar datos de una lista a excel

Tags: php, oracle

Buenas mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo este problema:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 800 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tmails\vendor\imangazaliev\didom\src\DiDom\Document.php on line 418

pero ya aumente el tiempo de ejecucion y sigue sin funcionar:

Codigo donde aumente el tiempo de ejecucion

```
// Export records
    "EXPORT_ALL" => true, // Export all records
    "EXPORT_ALL_TIME_LIMIT" => 800, // Export all records time limit
    "EXPORT_ORIGINAL_VALUE" => false,
    "EXPORT_FIELD_CAPTION" => false, // True to export field caption
    "EXPORT_FIELD_IMAGE" => true, // True to export field image
    "EXPORT_CSS_STYLES" => false, // True to export CSS styles
    "EXPORT_MASTER_RECORD" => true, // True to export master record
    "EXPORT_MASTER_RECORD_FOR_CSV" => false, // True to export master record for CSV
    "EXPORT_DETAIL_RECORDS" => true, // True to export detail records
    "EXPORT_DETAIL_RECORDS_FOR_CSV" => false, // True to export detail records for CSV
    "EXPORT_CLASSES" => [
        "email" => "ExportEmail",
        "html" => "ExportHtml",
        "word" => "ExportWord",
        "excel" => "ExportExcel",
        "pdf" => "ExportPdf",
        "csv" => "ExportCsv",
        "xml" => "ExportXml",
        "json" => "ExportJson"
```

En otra lista de datos que tengo si funciona la exportacion pero en otra lista la cual tiene mas datos no funciona

Comment: ¿qué tiene el código que ver con una base de datos Oracle?

Comment: el error claramente dice: **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 800 seconds exceeded**, tu codigo esta excediendo el tiempo de ejecucion, lo que tienes programado o consume mucho tiempo (mucha data) o entre en un bucle infinito... problema de arquitectura y/o logica